# How to schedule job with script in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server I am not getting SQL Server agent option to schedule job, So I am script to auto run it. I have procedure which has insert and delete process. Note I want to execute it daily at 4:40 AM

I have tried but I am getting this error

> Msg 8146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Union_BI, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 3]
>   Procedure Union_BI has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

```html
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX); 
SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement =  STUFF
(
    (       
         SELECT N' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ' + '[' + SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]) + '].[' + [name] + ']'
        FROM [sys].[tables]
        WHERE [name] LIKE  'TRNS%9' or  [name] LIKE  'TRNS%20'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1
    ,10
    ,''
);
Delete from TRNS ; insert into TRNS EXEC sp_executesql  @DynamicTSQLStatement
```

Above is my procedure
    USE Snowman_Attn;
    GO
    EXEC Snowman_Attn.dbo.Union_BI
         @job_name = N'Auto Union_BI', 
        @step_name        = N'Step 
        ,@subsystem        = N'TSQL'
        ,@database_name    = 'Snowman_Attn' 
        ,@command          = N'Exec Union_BI;'
        ,@server_name = 'SLL-DSK-046' 
        ,@freq_type              = 4 
        ,@freq_interval          = 1 
        ,@freq_subday_type       = 4 
        ,@freq_subday_interval   = 60 
        ,@freq_recurrence_factor = 1 
        ,@schedule_name    = N'Auto Union_BI' ; 
    GO

It should run my procedure `EXEC Snowman_Attn.dbo.Union_BI` at 4:40 AM

Comment: Your procedure having input parameter. please add input parameter in @command value. If you execute Exec Union_BI you will get same error.So you add input parameter in this query.

Comment: @B.Muthamizhselvi Sir I have added my procedure above, please help what will be command Value, I am new, I want auto run my procedure

Answer (score 0):

is this copy-pasted script from your db? There is lacking one apostrophe after 'Step'

```
  USE Snowman_Attn;
GO
EXEC Snowman_Attn.dbo.Union_BI
     @job_name = N'Auto Union_BI', 
    @step_name        = N'Step'
    ,@subsystem        = N'TSQL'
    ,@database_name    = 'Snowman_Attn' 
    ,@command          = N'Exec Union_BI;'
    ,@server_name = 'SLL-DSK-046' 
    ,@freq_type              = 4 
    ,@freq_interval          = 1 
    ,@freq_subday_type       = 4 
    ,@freq_subday_interval   = 60 
    ,@freq_recurrence_factor = 1 
    ,@schedule_name    = N'Auto Union_BI' ; 
GO
```